# How to echo only a part of preg_replace string?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've searched but there's nothing that really helps. I'm learning PHP and trying to output the value of $1, after preg_replace has applied the regex rules.

I only want to be left with `<span>$1</span>`, and the rest of the string needs stripping. Note that the string is highly variable so I can't set custom strstr for example to remove the word 'Get' as there are many variations.

```
  $the_coupon_title = 'Get 10% off at Walmart';
       $the_coupon_title = preg_replace(
            '/((£\d+\.?\d{0,2}|\d+\.?\d{0,2}%)\s+(off)+)/i',
            '<span>$1</span>',
            $the_coupon_title
        );
      echo $the_coupon_title;       
        
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `preg_replace` is the right method for what you want?

Comment: What exactly is the output of that currently? And what is the goal of this piece of code?

Comment: try something like `'/^.*?((£\d+\.?\d{0,2}|\d+\.?\d{0,2}%)\s+(off)+).*$/i'`

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/AFKJX

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the match and wrap with `span` tag:

```php
$the_coupon_title = 'Get 10% off at Walmart';
$the_coupon_title = preg_match(
            '/(£)?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?(1)|%)\s+off/iu',
            $the_coupon_title,
            $m
        );
echo '<span>', htmlspecialchars($m[0], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5), '</span>';
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/YDB5K). [New regex](https://regex101.com/r/khQaUp/1) details:

- `(£)?` - An optional group #1: a `£` char
- `\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - one or more digits and then an optional sequence of `.` and one or two digits
- `(?(1)|%)` - if `£` was not captured in Group 1 match `%` here
- `\s+off` - one or more whitespaces and `off` string.

Another approach is to match any text up to the pattern of yours, capture the value matched with the pattern, and then match the rest of the string and replace the match with the captured substring:

```php
echo preg_replace(
    '/^.*?((£)?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?(2)|%)\s+off).*/iu',
    '<span>$1</span>', 
    $the_coupon_title);
```

See [another PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/JUlk1). Note the `\1` to `\2` change since now the pound symbol is captured into Group 2. It is also prone to HTML injection.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here right? Looks good to me.